# GAS getPageElementType in Google Slides Logging output too large. Truncating output

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

Is there a trick to using getPageElementType?

If you use this function you get "Logging output too large. Truncating output. pe type" followed by a meaningless dump of something. Is the only way to determine page element type to use the select / case structure and go through the entire enum?

Here is my code:

```
function minimalCode() {
  
  const presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  const slides = presentation.getSlides();

  slides.forEach(slide => {
    slide.getPageElements().forEach(pe => {
      if (pe.getPageElementType() === 'SHAPE')
        console.log('pe type:  SHAPE' );
      else
        console.log('keep quessing the pe type - it is not a SHAPE' );

      console.log('- - - - - - - - - - - ' );
      console.log('pe type: ', pe.getPageElementType() )
      return;
    } );  // for each pe
    return;
  } );  // for each slide
}
```

Here is the result:

```
Mar 10, 2021, 2:35:47 PM    Debug   keep quessing the pe type - it is not a SHAPE
Mar 10, 2021, 2:35:47 PM    Debug   - - - - - - - - - - - 
Mar 10, 2021, 2:35:47 PM    Debug   Logging output too large. Truncating output. pe type:  { toString: [Function: toString],
  name: [Function: toString],
  toJSON: [Function: toString],
  ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
  compareTo: [Function: compareTo],
  UNSUPPORTED_PAGE_ELEMENT: 
   { toString: [Function: toString],
     name: [Function: toString],
     toJSON: [Function: toString],
     ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
     compareTo: [Function: compareTo],
     UNSUPPORTED_PAGE_ELEMENT: [Circular],
     UNSUPPORTED: 
      { toString: [Function: toString],
        name: [Function: toString],
        toJSON: [Function: toString],
        ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
        compareTo: [Function: compareTo],
        UNSUPPORTED_PAGE_ELEMENT: [Circular],
        UNSUPPORTED: [Circular],
        SHAPE: [Circular],
        IMAGE: [Object],
        VIDEO: [Object],
        TABLE: [Object],
        GROUP: [Object],
        LINE: [Object],
        WORD_ART: [Object],
        SHEETS_CHART: [Object],
        AUDIO: [Object] },
     SHAPE: [Circular],
     IMAGE: 
      { toString: [Function: toString],
        name: [Function: toString],
        toJSON: [Function: toString],
        ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
        compareTo: [Function: compareTo],
        UNSUPPORTED_PAGE_ELEMENT: [Circular],
        UNSUPPORTED: [Object],
        SHAPE: [Circular],
        IMAGE: [Circular],
        VIDEO: [Object],
        TABLE: [Object],
        GROUP: [Object],
        LINE: [Object],
        WORD_ART: [Object],
        SHEETS_CHART: [Object],
        AUDIO: [Object] },
     VIDEO: 
      { toString: [Function: toString],
        name: [Function: toString],
        toJSON: [Function: toString],
        ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
        compareTo: [Function: compareTo],
        UNSUPPORTED_PAGE_ELEMENT: [Circular],
        UNSUPPORTED: [Object],
        SHAPE: [Circular],
        IMAGE: [Object],
        VIDEO: [Circular],
        TABLE: [Object],
        GROUP: [Object],
        LINE: [Object],
        WORD_ART: [Object],
        SHEETS_CHART: [Object],
        AUDIO: [Object] },
     TABLE: 
      { toString: [Function: toString],
        name: [Function: toString],
        toJSON: [Function: toString],
        ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
        compareTo: [Function: compareTo],
        UNSUPPORTED_PAGE_ELEMENT: [Circular],
        UNSUPPORTED: [Object],
        SHAPE: [Circular],
        IMAGE: [Object],
        VIDEO: [Object],
        TABLE: [Circular],
        GROUP: [Object],
        LINE: [Object],
        WORD_ART: [Object],
        SHEETS_CHART: [Object],
        AUDIO: [Object] },
     GROUP: 
      { toString: [Function: toString],
        name: [Function: toString],
        toJSON: [Function: toString],
        ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
        compareTo: [Function: compareTo],
        UNSUPPORTED_PAGE_ELEMENT: [Circular],
        UNSUPPORTED: [Object],
        SHAPE: [Circular],
        IMAGE: [Object],
        VIDEO: [Object],
        TABLE: [Object],
        GROUP: [Circular],
        LINE: [Object],
        WORD_ART: [Object],
        SHEETS_CHART: [Object],
        AUDIO: [Object] },
     LINE: 
      { toString: [Function: toString],
        name: [Function: toString],
        toJSON: [Function: toString],
        ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
        compareTo: [Function: compareTo],
        UNSUPPORTED_PAGE_ELEMENT: [Circular],
        UNSUPPORTED: [Object],
        SHAPE: [Circular],
        IMAGE: [Object],
        VIDEO: [Object],
        TABLE: [Object],
        GROUP: [Object],
        LINE: [Circular],
        WORD_ART: [Object],
        SHEETS_CHART: [Object],
        AUDIO: [Object] },
     WORD_ART: 
      { toString: [Function: toString],
        name: [Function: toString],
        toJSON: [Function: toString],
        ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
        compareTo: [Function: compareTo],
        UNSUPPORTED_PAGE_ELEMENT: [Circular],
        UNSUPPORTED: [Object],
        SHAPE: [Circular],
        IMAGE: [Object],
        VIDEO: [Object],
        TABLE: [Object],
        GROUP: [Object],
        LINE: [Object],
        WORD_ART: [Circular],
        SHEETS_CHART: [Object],
        AUDIO: [Object] },
     SHEETS_CHART: 
      { toString: [Function: toString],
        name: [Function: toString],
        toJSON: [Function: toString],
        ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
        compareTo: [Function: compareTo],
        UNSUPPORTED_PAGE_ELEMENT: [Circular],
        UNSUPPORTED: [Object],
        SHAPE: [Circular],
        IMAGE: [Object],
        VIDEO: [Object],
        TABLE: [Object],
        GROUP: [Object],
        LINE: [Object],
        WORD_ART: [Object],
        SHEETS_CHART: [Circular],
        AUDIO: [Object] },
     AUDIO: 
      { toString: [Function: toString],
        name: [Function: toString],
        toJSON: [Function: toString],
        ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
        compareTo: [Function: compareTo],
        UNSUPPORTED_PAGE_ELEMENT: [Circular],
        UNSUPPORTED: [Object],
        SHAPE: [Circular],
        IMAGE: [Object],
        VIDEO: [Object],
        TABLE: [Object],
        GROUP: [Object],
        LINE: [Object],
        WORD_ART: [Object],
        SHEETS_CHART: [Object],
        AUDIO: [Circular] } },
  UNSUPPORTED: 
   { toString: [Function: toString],
     name: [Function: toString],
     toJSON: [Function: toString],
     ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
     compareTo: [Function: compareTo],
     UNSUPPORTED_PAGE_ELEMENT: 
      { toString: [Function: toString],
        name: [Function: toString],
        toJSON: [Function: toString],
        ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
        compareTo: [Function: compareTo],
        UNSUPPORTED_PAGE_ELEMENT: [Circular],
        UNSUPPORTED: [Circular],
        SHAPE: [Circular],
        IMAGE: [Object],
        VIDEO: [Object],
        TABLE: [Object],
        GROUP: [Object],
        LINE: [Object],
        WORD_ART: [Object],
        SHEETS_CHART: [Object],
        AUDIO: [Object] },
     UNSUPPORTED: [Circular],
     SHAPE: [Circular],
     IMAGE: 
      { toString: [Function: toString],
        name: [Function: toString],
        toJSON: [Function: toString],
        ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
        compareTo: [Function: compareTo],
        UNSUPPORTED_PAGE_ELEMENT: [Object],
        UNSUPPORTED: [Circular],
        SHAPE: [Circular],
        IMAGE: [Circular],
        VIDEO: [Object],
        TABLE: [Object],
        GROUP: [Object],
        LINE: [Object],
        WORD_ART: [Object],
        SHEETS_CHART: [Object],
        AUDIO: [Object] },
     VIDEO: 
      { toString: [Function: toString],
        name: [Function: toString],
        toJSON: [Function: toString],
        ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
        compareTo: [Function: compareTo],
        UNSUPPORTED_PAGE_ELEMENT: [Object],
        UNSUPPORTED: [Circular],
        SHAPE: [Circular],
        IMAGE: [Object],
        VIDEO: [Circular],
        TABLE: [Object],
        GROUP: [Object],
        LINE: [Object],
        WORD_ART: [Object],
        SHEETS_CHART: [Object],
        AUDIO: [Object] },
     TABLE: 
      { toString: [Function: toString],
        name: [Function: toString],
        toJSON: [Function: toString],
        ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
        compareTo: [Function: compareTo],
        UNSUPPORTED_PAGE_ELEMENT: [Object],
        UNSUPPORTED: [Circular],
        SHAPE: [Circular],
        IMAGE: [Object],
        VIDEO: [Object],
        TABLE: [Circular],
        GROUP: [Object],
        LINE: [Object],
        WORD_ART: [Object],
        SHEETS_CHART: [Object],
        AUDIO: [Object] },
     GROUP: 
      { toString: [Function: toString],
        name: [Function: toString],
        toJSON: [Function: toString],
        ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
        compareTo: [Function: compareTo],
        UNSUPPORTED_PAGE_ELEMENT: [Object],
        UNSUPPORTED: [Circular],
        SHAPE: [Circular],
        IMAGE: [Object],
        VIDEO: [Object],
        TABLE: [Object],
        GROUP: [Circular],
        LINE: [Object],
        WORD_ART: [Object],
        SHEETS_CHART: [Object],
        AUDIO: [Object] },
     LINE: 
      { toString: [Function: toString],
        name: [Function:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, there is a trick to it. When you invoke `getPageElementType()` it returns an enumerated type. That enumerated type's value is different depending on the context in which its used.

When you used it to test equality via `getPageElementType() === "SHAPE"`, its evaluated as a string, and behind the scenes the `toString()` method is implicitly called on the enumerated type returned by `getPageElementType()`, which returns the string `"SHAPE"`, so the equality test evaluates as TRUE.

When you pass that enumerated type to `console.log()`, the enumerated type is evaluated as an object and all its enumerable properties are printed out instead.

If you want to print out the string representation from `console.log()` you have to explicitly call the `toString()` method on the enumerated type (and this holds true for all enumerated types in Apps Script).

So, in short, do this:

```js
function minimalCode() {
  
  const presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  const slides = presentation.getSlides();

  slides.forEach(slide => {
    slide.getPageElements().forEach(pe => {
      if (pe.getPageElementType() === 'SHAPE')
        console.log('pe type:  SHAPE' );
      else
        console.log('keep quessing the pe type - it is not a SHAPE' );

      console.log('- - - - - - - - - - - ' );
      console.log('pe type: ', pe.getPageElementType().toString());
      return;
    } );  // for each pe
    return;
  } );  // for each slide
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Console.log()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console#log) outputs a blank DEBUG level message to Stackdriver Logging. You can use [Logger.log(data)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#logdata) instead.

### Sample Code:

```
function minimalCode() {
  
  const presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  const slides = presentation.getSlides();

  slides.forEach(slide => {
    slide.getPageElements().forEach(pe => {
      if (pe.getPageElementType() === "SHAPE")
        Logger.log('pe type:  SHAPE' );
      else
        Logger.log('keep quessing the pe type - it is not a SHAPE' );

      Logger.log('- - - - - - - - - - - ' );
      Logger.log('pe type: '+ pe.getPageElementType() )
      return;
    } );  // for each pe
    return;
  } );  // for each slide
}
```

### Output:

```
6:21:38 AM  Notice  Execution started
6:21:40 AM  Info    keep quessing the pe type - it is not a SHAPE
6:21:40 AM  Info    - - - - - - - - - - - 
6:21:40 AM  Info    pe type: SHAPE
6:21:40 AM  Info    keep quessing the pe type - it is not a SHAPE
6:21:40 AM  Info    - - - - - - - - - - - 
6:21:40 AM  Info    pe type: IMAGE
6:21:40 AM  Info    keep quessing the pe type - it is not a SHAPE
6:21:40 AM  Info    - - - - - - - - - - - 
6:21:40 AM  Info    pe type: TABLE
6:21:40 AM  Notice
```

### Note:

- In your current code, even though the page element type is already a `SHAPE`, the if condition was not triggered. To fix this use `if (pe.getPageElementType() == "SHAPE")`

**Output:**

```
6:27:30 AM  Notice  Execution started
6:27:31 AM  Info    pe type:  SHAPE
6:27:31 AM  Info    - - - - - - - - - - - 
6:27:31 AM  Info    pe type: SHAPE
6:27:31 AM  Info    keep quessing the pe type - it is not a SHAPE
6:27:31 AM  Info    - - - - - - - - - - - 
6:27:31 AM  Info    pe type: IMAGE
6:27:31 AM  Info    keep quessing the pe type - it is not a SHAPE
6:27:31 AM  Info    - - - - - - - - - - - 
6:27:31 AM  Info    pe type: TABLE
6:27:31 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```